# NodeJS TCP reverse proxy module (IP Forwarding)

Tags: node.js, npm

I am in need of a TCP reverse proxy library for nodejs. The library needs to be able to forward the IP address. Ones I have currently found do not forward the IP address of the person connecting.

Comment: why not to use nginx? it already does it out of box

Comment: It's being used for a Minecraft server.

Comment: again: nginx, ha-proxy can do it out of box, and it can forward ip address in http headers.

Comment: https://www.inpimation.com/setup-nginx-reverse-proxy/

Comment: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/about-bungeecord/